# Ethernet Connection Issues 22.04 H12SSL-I

Tags: networking, 22.04, internet, ethernet, broadcom

## Issue

Sometimes I am able to connect to ethernet briefly, but then it stops working within a few minutes, and nothing I've tried (mainly disabling and re-enabling ethernet) seems to turn it back on.
Often I am not able to connect to ethernet in the first place.

Wifi works through a USB Wifi Adapter, but of course this is a slower connection and so I am working to debug ethernet.

Oddly, when I connect via ethernet sucessfully I often see multiple ethernet connections showing as connected rather than just one.

## Extra Info

### Software

Ubuntu Desktop 22.04

### Hardware

#### Mobo/CPU

- Supermicro H12SSL-I Motherboard
- AMD 7502 processor.

#### Network Controllers

- Dual gigabit LAN via Broadcom BCM5720 (I believe this is the standard plug in the board, tested)
- 1 Realtek RTL8211F PHY (dedicated IPMI) ( I don't have any IPMI connector/not familiar with this)
- USB -> Ethernet (Tested after others failed)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was accidentally plugging into the IPMI port instead of the ethernet ports.

After swapping to the other port it now all seems to be working.